# Image gallery / float issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having a bit of trouble getting an image gallery to act the way I want it to. The photos are stacking on top of each other, rather than sitting side by side. I tried to use the float property, but I think I'm doing it wrong. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

HTML:

`<div class="gallery">`

```
    <img src="art/abstract.jpg"><div class"gallery">Abstract Painting</div>

    <img src="art/graphite.jpg"><div class"gallery">Graphite Drawing</div>...
```

CSS:

```
.gallery img {
    display:inline-block;
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
}

.gallery {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use extra div (with class .wrapper below) to wrap image with it's description an then float it:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="wrapper"><img src="art/abstract.jpg"/><div class"gallery">Abstract Painting</div></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><img src="art/graphite.jpg"/><div class"gallery">Graphite Drawing</div></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10q2xn22/1/)

Also I think you can remove these styles:

```
.gallery img {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class"gallery">
```

You missed out '='

Correct it as:

```
<div class="gallery">
```